# Authorize on all PageModels?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

In my app I'm using Authentication. In my _Layout.cshtml I have this View Component:

```
@{
    var ctxUser = ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
}

@if (ctxUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated && ctxUser.IsInRole("Member"))
{
    // Shows name on member
}
else
{
    // Shows login button
}
```

My app have numerous pages mixed together. Some requires login, some don't. What I find strange is, that it's only on pages with `[Authorize(Roles = "Member", AuthenticationSchemes = "Member")]` on the PageModel, that my View Component shows the name of the member logged in. If not, it shows the login button.

I know, I can just put [Anonymous] on the PageModel too, but is this really necessary?

Comment: Did you forget to add `app.UseAuthentication()` in your Startup’s `Configure` method?

Comment: No, it's there. I have these: `app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseHttpsRedirection(); app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseCookiePolicy(); app.UseMvc();` Does the order matter?